# Promises not consistent Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4

I'm developing an app using Ionic 4. So, for this particular function I'm fetching records from the SQLite db in the phone and POSTing it to an API. I use promise to make sure that the current data is already posted before looping to the next and so on. It was working great and suddenly stopped working.

I seriously have no idea what happened since nothing changed in my code. I'm hoping someone could help me.

Sometimes, it's working but only 2 out of 4 or 1 out of 4 data is being sent into the db with others returning a ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object] in Chrome Debugger.

```
dataPush() {
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'database.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table', [])
      .then(res => {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
            this.array.push({
              data1: res.rows.item(i).data1,
              data2: res.rows.item(i).data2,
              data3: res.rows.item(i).data3,
              data4: res.rows.item(i).data4,
              data5: res.rows.item(i).data5,
              data6: res.rows.item(i).data6,
              sync: res.rows.item(i).sync
            })

            if (this.array[i].sync == "N") {

              this.http.post("API URL", this.array[i])
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                  res => { // Success
                    console.log(res);
                    resolve();
                  }
                );

            }
          }
        });
        return promise;
      }).catch(e => console.log('Sync Error'));
  }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

This is the function that is giving me problems. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Cheers

**EDIT**
The error is because it's creating a duplicate primary key and mysql doesn't allow it to enter the table (thus only one enters and others get rejected). I set my primary key based on the previous keys and plus one to the number (all done in the PHP api). It's the reason I implemented promises to make sure that the PHP side has fully completed the task (insert data into database) before the other data begins its way into the api. Any ideas why the promise is not working?

Comment: Can you please add a `.catch` block to your `.post` promise, and find out what the uncaught error is?

Comment: @user184994 i just checked. the error is because if creating a duplicate primary key and mysql doesn't allow it to enter the table. I set my primary key based on the previous keys and plus one to the number (all done in the PHP api). It's the reason i implemented promises to make sure that the php side has fully completed the task (insert data into database) before the other data begins its way into the api. any ideas?

Comment: Because promises are asynchronous, the code will not have finished executing before the next loop iteration starts. Rather than using a `for` loop, you'd be better off using recursion

Comment: ahh i see.. can you help me a little on the recursion part.. never did recursion before.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, build up your array. Once you have all of your items pushed into `this.array`, you can call a recursive function. The recursive function should look something like this:

```
sendToApi(i) {
    this.http.post("API URL", this.array[i])
        .toPromise()
        .then(
          res => { 
            // Success
            console.log(res);
            if (i < this.array.length - 1) {
              // Call it again for the next item
              sendToApi(++i);
            }
          }
        );
}
```

And to start it off, just call `sendToApi(0)`. Each time the `.post` completes, it will call `sendToApi` again, but with the next number in the sequence

Comment: for some reason, this causes an infinite loop.. it keeps on pushing the first data but infinitely.. hmm..

Comment: Are you sure you've got `sendToApi(i++);`? You can try `sendToApi(i + 1)` instead, but not sure it will make a difference...

Comment: yup.. trying that now.. its weird because it should've stopped since i only have 4 datas.. however it keeps on going till 500+.. hahahaha

Comment: Just tried, and yes, doing that or `sendToApi(++i)` will work

Comment: hahaha just tried as well.. all is working.. thanks a lot mate.. :D